# Thorough deletion of an iOS enterprise certificate

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

When a device hasn't encountered an enterprise certificate before, attempting to install an app signed with it produces a dialog saying something along the lines of, "Would you like to accept apps signed by *corporation name*?"  After the installation, I can delete both the app and the enterprise certificate (in Settings -> General -> Profile).

The problem is that I can't reproduce the initial conditions.

If I try to install an app signed with that certificate again, the device does not produce the same dialog.  It just allows the installation and reinstalls the certificate silently.  How can I completely remove the certificate and restore the device's innocence?

Comment: +1; The normal warning message would be "Are You Sure You Want To Open the Application "NAME" from the Developer "iPhone Distribution: DEV_NAME"?". I have also verified what you have said - I've never noticed it until now... out of curiosity, why would you want the message to appear again?

Comment: Thanks @Luke.  We recently had trouble installing an alpha version of an app on a device.  I just want to put my development iPad into exactly the same state as a target device to increase my confidence in my debugging.